# In C# how do you accomplish the same thing as a #define

Tags: c#, constants

Coming from a C background I'm used to defining the size of the buffer in the following way:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

How would you do the accomplish the same thing in C#?

Also does the all-caps K&R style fit in with normal C# Pascal/Camel case?

Comment: I second both answers (ctacke, Megacan).

Comment: CamelCase is just a coding convention. Nothing semantical.

Comment: Yes, but I'm just curious if C# programmers would define constants like BUFFER_SIZE, or just write it in Pascal Case like BufferSize.

Comment: I still tend to use all-caps for constants. One reason for that is that I do a lot of interop and importing constants from C headers would be even more of a pain than it already is if I had to rename them all :)

Comment: @Stu Mackellar: Check out Resharper for refactoring. Renaming is no problem. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
```

Do not use "static readonly" because it creates a variable. "const" are replaced at build time and do not create variables.

Comment: I consider this poor form.  If I have this is assembly A, and assembly B references it it can leads to unexpected behavior.  Change the value in assembly A and recompile and the old value will continue to be used in assembly B unless it is recompiled.

Comment: @ctacke This is exactly analogous to a #define in a C header file - every module that used it would need to be recompiled if its value changed. I agree with Vernicht +1

Comment: @ctacke: thats why I use constants with the PRIVATE modifier

Comment: @Stu Mackellar, Vernicht: I agree with ctacke. Using const is ok but you must ensure that you are not sharing across assemblies. If you go public make sure you are using readonly! Reference: Effective C# : Item 2 - Prefer readonly to const

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I prefer constants:

```
private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
```

Though, if it's public and you're a framework, you may want it to be a readonly to [avoid client recompiles](http://techblogs.wordpress.com/2008/07/01/constansts-in-cs-const-vs-readonly/).

Comment: Interesting - you prefer the const, even knowing the inherent danger?

Comment: If it is private to the assembly, there's no benefit for using the readonly variable over the constant.  There's only a danger if the constant is exposed to other assemblies.

Comment: Also: it's hard to imagine a case where you're distributing a framework and users of your framework wouldn't need to recompile for the new version anyway.

Comment: @ctacke - making the const private or internal solves that problem...very rarely would I ever expose a const as public. Besides that, I don't tend to make frameworks - so I expect dependent assemblies to recompile anyway.

Comment: Lots of "hard to imagine" and "rarely" items here.  If experience has taught me nothing in software development, it's always the rare bugs that bite me in the ass.  Getting in the habit of using a static read-only means I never have to think about "what if" or someone else changing the scope.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static readonly int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
```

I prefer this over a const due to the [compiler shenanigans that can happen](http://en.csharp-online.net/const,_static_and_readonly) with a const value (const is just used for replacement, so changing the value will not change it in any assembly compiled against the original).

Comment: I agree. I learned this from Effective C# : Item 2 - Prefer readonly to const.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use #define.

Define a constante: private const int BUFFER_SIZE
or readonly variable: private readonly int BUFFER_SIZE

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I decided to do that this way:

```
//C# replace C++ #define
struct define
{
    public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    //public const int STAN_LIMIT = 6;
    //public const String SIEMENS_FDATE = "1990-01-01";
}

//some code
byte[] buffer = new byte[define.BUFFER_SIZE];
```